# Python FileNotFoundError even though file is in same directory

Tags: python, django, import, pickle, filenotfounderror

I'm trying to use pickle to load a file within the same directory but I am getting FileNotFoundError for some reason. This is my code in views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
import pickle

model = pickle.load(open('braintumor.pkl', 'rb'))

def say_hello(request):
    return render(request, 'hello.html', {'name:': 'Alisha'})

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html', { 'a' : 1})
```

And this is my file structure:

webapp

- views.py
- braintumor.pkl

It's a django app so is more complex than this but it wasn't important to list every file and directory, there is definitely no spelling errors and the pkl file is definitely in the same directory as views.py.
I also tried a file structure like this:

webapp

- views.py
- models

  -braintumor.pkl

And then I tried using the import statement: "from models import braintumor" but that didn't work because I got an error saying that there is no such file or directory 'models'. I also tried loading it with the statement: "model = pickle.load(open('models/braintumor.pkl', 'rb'))" but still get FileNotFoundError! It seems no matter what I do, python simply cannot load anything and I have no idea what to do. I see nothing wrong with any of the solutions I tried. Please help, it would be crazy to scrap my project because of something so simple.

Comment: Have you tried `.models` instead of the `models`?